# Embedding layer before LSTM layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, embeddings

I am toying around with a clustering and churn prediction framework, *cluschurn* which they deployed in production at Snap, Inc. In their research paper, [paper_link](https://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/pdf/kdd18_cyang.pdf), they use 14 days of user data and treat it as a time series. They do some transformations and they have a have a 3-dimensional dataset which is 12x14xm users; each user, m, has 12 daily features for a total of 14 days. This set gets fed into an LSTM so that each LSTM timestep has receives a 12-dimensional vector. Hopefully, I worded this right so it's understandable. They were able to improve their results by adding a embedding layer between the input and the LSTM layer.

> We connect a fully connected feedforward neural network to the
>   original daily activity vactors, which converts users' sparse activity
>   features of each day into distributional activity embeddings...

[image]

I'm completely confused on what this looks like dimension-wise and am confused if there is a fully connected network before each LSTM timestep or is there one fully connected network before the feeding the LSTM? For example, is the 3-dimensional data set flattened and then fed into a fully connected network and then reshaped back into a 3-dimension dataset that has 14 timesteps?

I made these concepts to help clarify what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward approach to understand their proposal is to look at their source code, which is linked from the article: https://github.com/yangji9181/ClusChurn/blob/master/model.py#L35

It reveals that the "embedding" is obtained by means of a mere linear layer.

Comment: I did not understand this answer so I did not mark it as right. I put 2 pictures up in my question asking for clarification on what the architecture is supposed to look like because I don't fully understand it and needed help in a deeper understanding on how it works. I'm not saying your answer is wrong or anything like that, it's just that it didn't help me understand the problem I was having. I do know the answer after lots of digging around and I should probably post an answer to explain my findings.

Comment: Sorry that my answer was not clear. I think it would be great if you posted the answer that made it clear for you.

Comment: No worries, thank you for posting though because maybe others will be able to figure it out. Yes, I will post my answer when I get some free time.